# URL for connecting to a remote database using android

Tags: php, android, json

I'm a new guy for android development.I want to connect to remote database in cpanel and show data according to username and password.these are my codes up to now

login form android xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Enter your username"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_username"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_username"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Enter your password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Username"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Username"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_log"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_password"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_log"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_log"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my java code for above xml layout

```
package com.example.remotedb1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String strURL = "http://cyberi-tech.com/khacheb/sig1.php";

      StringBuilder sb=null;

      TextView  inlog;
      TextView inpass;
      Button log;
      Button cancel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        inlog = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        inpass = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        log = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_log);
        cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);


        log.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            InputStream is = null;
            String result = "";

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", inlog.getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", inpass.getText().toString()));

            try{
              HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strURL);
              httppost.setEntity(new  UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
              HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
              HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
              is = entity.getContent();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
              Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }

            // Convertion de la requÃªte en string
            try{
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              String line = null;
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
              }
              is.close();
              result=sb.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
              Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            try{
              JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
              for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("log_tag","cin: "+json_data.getInt("cin")+
                  ", accountNb: "+json_data.getString("accountNb")+
                  ", username: "+json_data.getString("username")+
                  ", password: "+json_data.getString("password")
                );
              }
            }
            catch(JSONException e){         
              Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }       
          }
        });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();   
          }
        });



    }


}
```

This is my php file

```
<?php
/**
* Database config variables
*/
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';  
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : ''; 

if(strlen($username) && strlen($password)) {

mysql_connect("localhost","allround_root","ravi12345");//this is my cpanel database,username,password.
mysql_select_db("allround_db");

$username = mysql_real_escape($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape($password);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT cin,accountNb,username , password FROM users WHERE    username = ‘$username’ AND password = ‘$password’");  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " . mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
  $output[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
}
 //end of if
?>
```

Sir/Madem my quection is

there is string url "http://cyberi-tech.com/khacheb/sig1.php".I cannot understand where i store this php file in my cpanel?

Also "cyberi-tech.com" is refer for -hostname
"sig1.php" is refer for -my php file
but i cannot understand "khacheb" refer for ?? so please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`khacheb` refers to a folder within your webserver root directory which contains your `sig1.PHP` file. You should put your code to connect to the `PHP` file in a separate thread via [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), here is an example of implementation also [example of asynctask](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html). I hope this helped you.